# Adding subdirectories in Samba

Tags: samba

Just an easy question about Samba's conf file.
I have successfully created a samba server on my computer, but having troubles with the configuration file. I would like to create a server where each user, lets say, Alice, Bob, Chris and Doug, to have a 'home' each consisting of a folder that are hosted in different parts of a hard drive.

My ideal samba server directory set-up:   (Actual Hardrive locations are in brackets)
[image: Ideal Setup directory tree]
*sorry for the picture, I just couldn't format it right on the website*

Any ideas?
Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the hard drive, you seem to want to organize the folders like /purpose/user, but on the Samba share it's the other way around (/user/purpose). Is there a reason why you want to do it that way? Because if it's no biggie to you, then I it would be a lot easier if you organized the folders on the hard drive the same as the Samba share. Also, do you want to restrict each user so that he or she can only access their own files, or is it okay if anyone on your network can read, write, delete, etc in anyone else's files? The answer to this question would affect whether you create a separate Samba share for each user versus having one Samba share for all.

If you have one Samba share for all, then just create a single mount point (i.e. /media/share) and when any user connects to the Samba share, they get all the child folders the same way they are organized on the Samba server. On the other hand, if you want separate access privileges, and hence one Samba share for each user, then still the only folders you would need to create on the hard drive are the separate mount points for each user (i.e. /media/Alice, /media/Bob, etc). Then, when each user connects to his or her Samba share and they automatically get the folder hierarchy described on the left in your picture.